# Increasing basis dimension in mgcv to maximum value results in problematic residual plots

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I have a dataset consisting of 100 (x, y) observations

```
    specs  means
1       1 1.0000
2       2 1.9031
3       3 2.7147
4       4 3.4322
5       5 4.0896
6       6 4.7011
7       7 5.2036
8       8 5.7023
9       9 6.1321
10     10 6.5145
11     11 6.8642
12     12 7.1808
13     13 7.4519
14     14 7.7079
15     15 7.9292
16     16 8.1652
17     17 8.3244
18     18 8.4945
19     19 8.6496
20     20 8.7873
21     21 8.9045
22     22 9.0147
23     23 9.1111
24     24 9.2111
25     25 9.2904
26     26 9.3589
27     27 9.4173
28     28 9.4826
29     29 9.5279
30     30 9.5710
31     31 9.6163
32     32 9.6571
33     33 9.6896
34     34 9.7199
35     35 9.7562
36     36 9.7726
37     37 9.7944
38     38 9.8134
39     39 9.8368
40     40 9.8552
41     41 9.8677
42     42 9.8805
43     43 9.8897
44     44 9.9086
45     45 9.9109
46     46 9.9198
47     47 9.9294
48     48 9.9345
49     49 9.9439
50     50 9.9463
51     51 9.9479
52     52 9.9604
53     53 9.9603
54     54 9.9664
55     55 9.9678
56     56 9.9747
57     57 9.9738
58     58 9.9764
59     59 9.9798
60     60 9.9811
61     61 9.9822
62     62 9.9850
63     63 9.9855
64     64 9.9879
65     65 9.9885
66     66 9.9899
67     67 9.9913
68     68 9.9929
69     69 9.9951
70     70 9.9940
71     71 9.9946
72     72 9.9948
73     73 9.9952
74     74 9.9968
75     75 9.9972
76     76 9.9960
77     77 9.9975
78     78 9.9975
79     79 9.9969
80     80 9.9974
81     81 9.9983
82     82 9.9978
83     83 9.9987
84     84 9.9983
85     85 9.9986
86     86 9.9991
87     87 9.9988
88     88 9.9989
89     89 9.9993
90     90 9.9983
91     91 9.9990
92     92 9.9988
93     93 9.9985
94     94 9.9992
95     95 9.9990
96     96 9.9994
97     97 9.9995
98     98 9.9992
99     99 9.9998
100   100 9.9993
```

In fitting a cubic regression spline GAM to my data,

```
HAC.cr <- gam(means ~ s(specs, bs = "cr", k = 100), optimizer = c("outer", "bfgs"), data = d)
```

k = 20 is problematic. I then tried increasing k to be equal to the number of data points (i.e., k = 100) on a hunch. The fit is no better. k cannot be increased any further because there cannot be more basis functions than there are data.

Clearly one should not have to go this far in fitting a GAM. In most cases a large enough k will suffice.

My gam.check() output is below. The numeric output does not appear problematic to my eyes, but the residual plots do. For instance, there seems to be a heteroscedasticity (decreasing variance with the mean) issue in the linear predictor.

```
Method: GCV   Optimizer: magic
Smoothing parameter selection converged after 4 iterations.
The RMS GCV score gradient at convergence was 1.712629e-14 .
The Hessian was positive definite.
Model rank =  100 / 100 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

           k'   edf k-index p-value
s(specs) 99.00 65.73    1.66       1
```

[image]

```
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
means ~ s(specs, bs = "cr", k = 100)

Parametric coefficients:
         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 9.1000310  0.0004169   21828   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
           edf Ref.df      F p-value    
s(specs) 65.73  79.24 250657  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =      1   Deviance explained =  100%
GCV = 5.2235e-05  Scale est. = 1.738e-05  n = 100
```

[image]

Any ideas on how to go about getting around the issue, or is this as good as it gets (sadly)?

Comment: What leads you to believe that the features you see in the plots etc. are not real features of the data and are in fact due to `gam` fit problems?

Comment: Are these simulated data? (There doesn't appear to be any error/noise here - or it is *very* small in magnitude relative to the signal.) In this situation, you can do as well as your model (which uses about 65 EDF) with an adaptive spline, which ends up using about 12 EDF with the other options you used: `m2 <- gam(means ~ s(specs, bs = "ad", k = 40), data = df, optimizer = c("outer", "bfgs"))`. What this suggests to me is that the curvature of the true data generating process varies a lot & requires different smoothness parameters in different regions to stop it overfitting.

Comment: @GavinSimpson... Yes this is simulated data that I generated from a simulation that I built. The curves that result from this simulation are highly variable (but all monotonically increasing towards an asymptote). Some curves may level off more slowly than others. I was thinking that an adaptive smooth could work here since the curve increases very rapidly initially, The simulation mimics the behaviour of species area and rarefaction curves in ecological modelling. There is no noise... the GAM essentially interpolates that data, rather than smoothing it...